# How do I open the correct part of a multi-part Bootstrap 3 accordion menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on adding an accordion menu to a project and I'm getting stuck trying to get the accordion menu to expand the correct section and highlight the current selection based on the URL (the latter part I have sorted out by just changing adding `class="active"` to the entry matched with the page URL using some JS.

My issue is that I have two accordion sections and would like to open the one containing this entry when I navigate to the page. I've tried all sorts of hacks and I have a feeling I'm missing something here. The menu's default state is to have all sections closed on load as can be seen in my HTML here (I've simplified and sanitized it a bit):

```
<div class="accordion fontsome" id="leftMenu">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <a class="accordion-toggle accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#leftMenu" href="#collapseTwo">
                    Red Products <i class="pull-right fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="product?pid=1">Product 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="product?pid=2">Product 2</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li><a href="product?pid=3">Product 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="product?pid=4">Product 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-group">
            <a class="accordion-toggle accordion-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#leftMenu" href="#collapseThree">
                    Blue Products <i class="pull-right fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-body collapse" style="height: 0px; ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="product?pid=5">Product 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="product?pid=6">Product 6</a></li>
                    <hr>
                    <li><a href="product?pid=7">Product 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="product?pid=8">Product 8</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any pointers would be great. I've omitted my attempted JS hacks based on articles and my own ideas to get this to work as none were working. Can be provided if they would help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is the 'correct' way to do it, or just another hacky solution, but if I had this problem I'd probably stick the accordions into a PHP file. I could then read the value from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and amend the HTML output depending on which one should be active to display the correct accordion. I like designing all of my sites in a really modular way, so I normally use this technique to set the `active` class in navbars when I have them in separate PHP files from the actual page they are in.

Of course if your server isn't set up to support PHP this is no help at all, but I hope this helps.

Comment: The site is, indeed, set up in PHP and is also quite modular. The one issue is that the pages are all generated using the same php template from db data and their category in the menu may change at any time. I suppose I could hard-code it in to PHP that any product in a given range or set of numbers will render the correct part of the menu open. While it's not as maintenance-free and elegant as I'd like, and still a bit hacky, it could be a "good enough" solution. I'll play with it and report back :).

Comment: @DarwinAllen Sorry, only just noticed the Get parameters. Guess I should have realised it had PHP lol. Getting a bit more bloated perhaps, but could you maybe link it into an SQL query to check the product category rather than hardcoding the id values when generating the accordions?